# Undefined control sequence \end{frame}

Tags: beamer, errors, compiling

I'm having trouble woking with this code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Class options include: notes, notesonly, handout, trans,
%                        hidesubsections, shadesubsections,
%                        inrow, blue, red, grey, brown

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\decimalpoint

% Theme for beamer presentation.
% \usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS} 
\usecolortheme{beaver}
% Other themes include: beamerthemebars, beamerthemelined, 
%                       beamerthemetree, beamerthemetreebars  

\title{Title}    % Enter your title between curly braces
\date{31 de mayo de 2013}
%\date{abril de 2013}                    % Enter the date or \today between curly braces

\begin{document}

% Creates title page of slide show using above information
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introducción}
\subsection{Problema}
\begin{frame}{Problema}
\paragraph{}
    Un comerciante de semillas asegura que el 80\% de sus semillas germinan existosamente. Cuatro clientes compraron un paquete cada uno
    y sembraron 100 semillas de éste. Los número de semillas que germinaron fueron 73, 76, 74 y 77.

    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{seeds.jpg}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I compile, it displays the error:

```
Undefined control sequence \end{frame}
```

though it generates the PDF file correctly. I'd like to get it working correctly since it is a little annoying to get that error every time I compile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. `\paragraph` is not defined in the `beamer` class. Besides, I don't think you should use a sectioning command (such as `\paragraph`, `\section`, `\subsection`, etc.) within a frame.

Comment: The undefined control sequence is `\paragraph`. Remove it, it would do nothing anyway. It's a sectioning command and it's rarely used also in normal LaTeX documents.

Comment: Thank you @Jubobs for your suggestion. And thank you both Jubobs and egreg for your answer, it works well.

Comment: This is not too localized, by the way, so I hope this is not on the path to deletion. It has helped me and at least six other people, who saw the inaccurate message in the title when the real error lay elsewhere (and not in the `end{frame}`) command.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

the error is actually

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \paragraph 

l.41 \end{frame}
```

For undefined command errors the command that is undefined is always the one at the end of the second line of the message, so `\paragraph` here.

the line

```
 l.41 \end{frame}
```

is reporting that the error was *detected* when TeX had read to line 41 at the end of the frame, this happens as `beamer` collects the entire frame as a macro argument so that it can do things with it, so TeX has read to the end of the frame before trying to execute the contents and finding `\paragraph` undefined.  Just delete the line with `\paragraph`.